# Django localization fill default language

Tags: python, django, localization

We are currently translating our django app using i18n.

Our app is fully written in english but now we want to add Spanish,

We already started to replace strings with trans but since msgid are in English we got this:

HTML

```
 <li><a href={% url 'users' %}><i class="fa fa-users"></i> {% trans "Users" %}</a></li>
```

django.po (en)

```
msgid "Users"
msgstr ""
```

django.po (es)

```
msgid "Users"
msgstr "Usuarios"
```

so, this is my question, since default language is english, is ok to leave just the key, instead of fill the same msgstr with "Users" again?

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to leave msgstr "" empty.
And it's also okay to not generate english translations (I mean locales/en/ folders) by running `django-admin makemessages -l es`

EDIT:

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files), they explain how to create translation files for German language like this as a default

Comment: Can you provide me some reference about this?